# Catching ALT+TAB for the window

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gtk

ALL,

We have a an application written with wxWidgets (wxGTK) and Qt.It is running on RHEL6 with FVWM window manager.

One of the window we have in that application is "Lock Screen" which is shown in the full-screen mode and does not have any decorations. The only way to get out of it should be to enter the password and press the "Authenticate" button.

However what we discover is that if the user starts up Terminal and then pulls up that "Lock Screen", (s)he can press ALT+TAB, switch to the Terminal and type whatever (s)he wants. We'd like to avoid it.

Is there any way possible to catch the "ALT+TAB" keystroke and do nothing when this "Lock Screen" window is displayed. The window is written with wxWidgets, but I'm asking about c++/Linux/gtk/qt in general.

TIA for any hints/advice community can provide.

[EDIT]

All I want is for the user to not be able to switch focus from the password field until the password is given and the "Authenticate" button is pressed.

[/EDIT]

And before you ask - there are couple of related questions on SO, which says solved, but they are for Windows/C#/WinForms/JAVA. If you can find something that will work on Linux with either GTK or Qt or maybe even FVWM internal settings I will gladly accept the answer.

Comment: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32335-disable-alt-tab

Comment: You don't only want to disable Alt+tab, you want to make sure your window is always on top, which is not the same (consider Windows+D, Windows+tab, etc...)

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you for the link. It is mostly Windows though. Also see my reply below to Magix.

Comment: @Magix, when our "Lock Screen" is displayed, it shows the password text field and the "Authenticate" button. The input focus is on the password text field. And so as long as I can't type on any other window - be it thru the ALT+TAB, Win+D etc). I'm happy. If "STAY_ON_TOP" will give me such an ability - I will also be happy. Thank you and sorry to not clarify this any further.

Comment: Additionally to "stay-on-top", [`QWidget::grabKeyboard()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabKeyboard) and [`QWidget::grabMouse()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabMouse) might be worth a try.